# passing json data in elasticsearch get request using rest-client ruby gem

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, rest-client

How do I execute the below query(given in [doc](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/request-body.html)) using rest client.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
'
```

I tried doing this:

```
q = '{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
'

r = JSON.parse(RestClient.get('http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search', q))
```

This threw up an error:

```
in `process_url_params': undefined method `delete_if' for #<String:0x8b12e18>     (NoMethodError)
    from /home/socialapps/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:40:in `initialize'
    from /home/socialapps/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `new'
    from /home/socialapps/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'
    from /home/socialapps/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient.rb:68:in `get'
    from get_check2.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

When I do the same using `RestClient.post`, it gives me the right results!. But the elasticsearch doc uses `XGET` in curl command for the search query and not `XPOST`. How do I get the `RestClient.get` method to work?

If there are alternate/better ways of doing this action, please suggest.

Comment: i think that this has nothing to do with get or post but with the code you have in ```get_check2.rb```. what is the actual response that you get from ES using RestClient? it's probably something that you handling the wrong way!

Comment: Elasticsearch queries seems to work just fine even you use a POST request. So we can use a simple rest client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RestClient can't send request bodies with `GET`. You've got two options:

Pass your query as the `source` URL parameter:

```
require 'rest_client'
require 'json'

# RestClient.log=STDOUT # Optionally turn on logging

q = '{
    "query" : { "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" } }
}
'
r = JSON.parse \
      RestClient.get( 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search',
                      params: { source: q } )

puts r
```

...or just use `POST`.

---

*UPDATE:* Fixed incorrect passing of the URL parameter, notice the `params` Hash.

Comment: Coffescript doesn't seem to support GET Bodies either.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else finds this. It IS possible, although not recommended, to send request bodies with GET by using the internal Request method that the main API uses to create it's calls.

```
RestClient::Request.execute( method: :get, 
                             url: 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search',
                             payload: {source: q} )
```

See [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/w/wgibbs-rest-client-1.0.5/RestClient/Request.html) for more details.