# Range query in ElasticSearch (GET without body)

Tags: json, elasticsearch

So very basic question about elasticsearch which the docs not answer very clearly (because they seem to go into many advanced details but miss the basic ones!).

Example: range query

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/range-query.html

Doesn't tell how to PERFORM the range, is it via the search endpoint?

And if it is, then how to do it via querystring? I mean, I want to do a GET, not a POST (because it's a query, not an insertion/modification). However the documention for GET requests doesn't tell how to use JSON like in the Range sample:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/uri-request.html

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: There are [common options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html) to many queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replying to myself thanks to @javanna:

In the RequestBody section of the Search docs:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/request-body.html

At the end, it says:

> The rest of the search request should be passed within the body itself. The body content can also be passed as a REST parameter named **source**.

So I guess that I need to use the search endpoint with the `source` attribute to pass json.

Comment: can you please explain how are you using source attribute with the search endpoint to get the range working? - I am having similar issue with date ranges, format yyyyMMddHHmmss within the body of the JSON

Comment: Nevermind, I guess I found it here (+1 for question in the first place) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988201/passing-json-data-in-elasticsearch-get-request-using-rest-client-ruby-gem

Comment: sorry it's been a very big while since I don't use elasticsearch

Answer (score 15):

Use the [Lucene query syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/queryparsersyntax.html):

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search?q=my_field:[0+TO+25]&pretty'
```

Comment: meh, I'm looking for still using the json syntax

Comment: That is obviously a better solution -- in your question, you explicitely ask how to do it without the JSON DSL definiton.

Comment: where do you read that? I say "the documention for GET requests doesn't tell how to use JSON like in the Range sample" so obviously I'm looking for the JSON solution

Answer (score 8):

Let's assume we have an index

`curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test`

And some documents

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/range/1 -d '{"age": 9}'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/range/2 -d '{"age": 12}'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/range/3 -d '{"age": 16}'
```

Now we can query these documents within a certain range via

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test/range/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "range" : {
            "age" : { 
                "from" : "10", 
                "to" : "20", 
                "include_lower" : true,
                "include_upper": true
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

This will return the documents 2 and 3.

<strike>I'm not sure if there is a way to perform these kind of complex queries via [URI request](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/uri-request.html), though.</strike>

**Edit**: Thanks to karmi here is the solution without JSON request:

`curl -XGET --globoff 'localhost:9200/test/range/_search?q=age:["10"+TO+"20"]&pretty=true'`

Comment: I'm sorry, the title of this question clearly states "without postbody" so I'm downvoting this

Comment: you cannot send body in most GET verb APIs (i.e. .NET)

Comment: I know that the answer is not perfectly fitting the question, but like I mentioned, I'm not sure if there is another way, since elasticsearch is expecting JSON objects for querying.

Comment: karmi posted the right way to do it, I added it to my answer as well

Comment: knocte: Two things: 1) ES allows POSTs to certain endpoints that are normally a GET (such as the search endpoint), because not all clients can send a GET with a body.  2) GETs with a body are technically compatible with HTTP/1.1.  Perhaps not recommended...but nothing incorrect.  See this for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body